# Snackbar animation android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-snackbar, snackbar

Can I disable the default Snackbar animation in android? If yes then how?
Please give me an example.

Also, I want to know how to set a custom animation on Snackbar. Then how can I set the animation on Snackbar? Please give me a detailed explanation of that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can implement your linear layout which acts like a snack bar

Comment: can u explain it @war_Hero

Comment: In new versión support library 24.2.1  animation show and close are  disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`, you can't do that since the animation is [hardcoded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java?autodive=0%2F%2F) (note private methods `animateViewIn()` and `animateViewOut()`). So your best bet is to use some third-party view. For example, [this](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/SnackBar) library mimics the behavior of a stock SnackBar and allows you to set your own custom animation right in your xml with `sb_inAnimation` and `sb_outAnimation`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a view-Group(linear/relative layouts) which will slide up from bottom(like stock snackbar animation), embed this viewgroup in the bottom of your parent layout which will cause it to appear almost like a snackbar.

Since you wanted to customize the stock snackbar i am not sure if you can proceed than using third party library you can do this